# Using a class to assign value to a variable (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, class

So, if I have a block in my main method that looks like this:

```
Classname** array2 = new ClassName* [sizeOfArray];
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++) {
    array2[i] = new ClassName(array1[i]);
}
```

What would I put in the class to assign array2 the same values as array1, assuming they are the same size?

I am aware that it would be easier to assign the values without using a class, but humor me.

Comment: This does not make any sense if we don't know the types of arrays and objects you are working with.

Comment: Is array2 a native array or object of a class say here ClassName. If it is a object then it is straight forward to use copy constructor to do your task, if it is native array then the assignment itself doesn't make any sense.

Comment: array1 is a native array, array2 is an object of the class. Both arrays are character arrays.

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on whether ClassName has any dynamically allocated data members.

For classes with no dynamically allocated memory, the default copy constructor would suffice and you do not need to add any thing more for ClassName to copy correctly.

If there are, write a copy constructor to copy those members.

```
class ClassName {
public:
    int * data;  // Dynamically allocated data members
    ...

    // Copy constructor
    ClassName(const ClassName & other)
    {
        data = new int;       // Allocate memory..
        *data = *other.data;  // and copy data member
    }
};
```

Comment: Updated to answer the edited question